# How to convert a File into a StorageObject (Google API)

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to store a file into Google NearLine using a java program and Google's Cloud Storage API. But I'm having difficulty finding out how to do this. 
I think I have to convert the File object into a StorageObject, but not sure how to do it.

Here's a link to the doc's for the StorageObject.
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1beta2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/model/StorageObject.html#set(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)

Thanks.

Note: I've been using this link as a guide:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples

However, this only shows you how to access the bucket, not upload files to the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

To upload files, use Storage.Objects.Insert: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1beta2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/Storage.Objects.Insert.html

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example of how to use it. Thanks